# Java JAX-WS Webmethod parameter inheritance

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

My jax-WS web service looks like this:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface SampleServer {

@WebMethod void doIt1(@WebParam Event event);

@WebMethod void doIt2(String aString);
}
```

The class Event is abstract, with some simple methods.
For example:
    public abstract class Event { private int param; ... getter / setter ...}

I wrote a client which can call doIt2 without errors, but I can't find a good solution to create a call to doIt1.

If I specify "@XMLSeeAlso" with subclasses on Event it works fine, but I think this is a stupid solution, because the web service should not work on specific client classes of type Event. I would like to have a separation of client and server classes.

Any hints are welcome. Thanks.